# How to go to the next page using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from all the 37 web pages from [this website](https://www.stfrancismedicalcenter.com/find-a-provider/).

The website I am scrapping doesn't allow going to the next page through the search bar.

This is the HTML written for the next button.

```
<a href="javascript:void('Next')" class="next">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" data-use="/cms/svg/site/icon_caret_right.36.svg">
        (path tag and data)
    </svg>
</a>
```

I know that this can be done with Selenium, but is there any way to do this with BeautifulSoup?

Is there any way to scrape data from the next page?

Comment: `requests` or `selenium` modules come to mind. it really depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Beautifulsoup is used to parse html, and has nothing to do with interacting with a website. you can indirectly use it to go to next pages if it's used to parse out some data or link that directs to a next page. But directly, BeautifulSoup is not the tool to navigate websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can go to each page using `requests` here. It's through a post request, that then uses the query page parameter to get back the data for sequential pages:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = 'https://www.stfrancismedicalcenter.com/find-a-provider/'


for page in range(1, 38):
    print(f'\t\tPage: {page}')
    payload = {
    '_m_': 'FindAPhysician',
    'PhysicianSearch$HDR0$PhysicianName': '',
    'PhysicianSearch$HDR0$SpecialtyIDs': '',
    'PhysicianSearch$HDR0$Distance': '5',
    'PhysicianSearch$HDR0$ZipCodeSearch': '',
    'PhysicianSearch$HDR0$Keywords': '',
    'PhysicianSearch$HDR0$LanguageIDs': '',
    'PhysicianSearch$HDR0$Gender': '',
    'PhysicianSearch$HDR0$InsuranceIDs': '',
    'PhysicianSearch$HDR0$AffiliationIDs': '',
    'PhysicianSearch$HDR0$NewPatientsOnly': '',
    'PhysicianSearch$HDR0$InNetwork': '',
    'PhysicianSearch$HDR0$HasPhoto': '',
    'PhysicianSearch$FTR01$PagingID': str(page)}
    
    response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    
    items = soup.find_all('li', {'class':re.compile("^half item-")})
    for item in items:
        itemName = item.find('div', {'class':'info'}).find_all('span')[0].text
        itemType = item.find('div', {'class':'info'}).find_all('span')[1].text
        phone = item.find('li', {'class':'inline-svg phone'}).text.strip()
        address = item.find('address').text.strip().replace('\t','')
        
        print(f'\n{itemName}\n{itemType}\n{phone}\n{address}\n')
```

Comment: be sure to accept the solution.